# Getting SparkFlumeProtocol and EventBatch not found errors when building Spark 1.6.2 on CentOS7

Tags: apache-spark, build, centos7

I was trying to build `Spark 1.6.2` on `CentOS7` and ran into the error below:

```
[error] /home/pateln16/spark-1.6.2/external/flume-sink/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/sink/SparkAvroCallbackHandler.scala:45: not found: type SparkFlumeProtocol
[error]   val transactionTimeout: Int, val backOffInterval: Int) extends SparkFlumeProtocol with Logging {
[error]                                                                  ^
[error] /home/pateln16/spark-1.6.2/external/flume-sink/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/sink/SparkAvroCallbackHandler.scala:70: not found: type EventBatch
[error]   override def getEventBatch(n: Int): EventBatch = {
[error]                                       ^
[error] /home/pateln16/spark-1.6.2/external/flume-sink/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/sink/TransactionProcessor.scala:80: not found: type EventBatch
[error]   def getEventBatch: EventBatch = {
[error]                      ^
[error] /home/pateln16/spark-1.6.2/external/flume-sink/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/sink/SparkSinkUtils.scala:25: not found: type EventBatch
[error]   def isErrorBatch(batch: EventBatch): Boolean = {
[error]                           ^
[error] /home/pateln16/spark-1.6.2/external/flume-sink/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/sink/SparkAvroCallbackHandler.scala:85: not found: type EventBatch
[error]         new EventBatch("Spark sink has been stopped!", "", java.util.Collections.emptyList())
[error]             ^
[warn] Class org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] Class org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] Class org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineFactory not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] Class org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ExecutionHandler not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] Class org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] Class org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.ExecutionHandler not found - continuing with a stub.
[warn] Class org.jboss.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup not found - continuing with a stub.
[error] /home/pateln16/spark-1.6.2/external/flume-sink/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/sink/SparkSink.scala:86: not found: type SparkFlumeProtocol
[error]     val responder = new SpecificResponder(classOf[SparkFlumeProtocol], handler.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem on Spark 2.0.0. I think the reason is that file 'external\flume-sink\src\main\avro\sparkflume.avdl' is not complied well.

The problem can be resolved by:

- Download Apache Avro
  http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html
  I downloaded all jar files into folder 'C:\Downloads\avro'.
- Go to folder 'external\flume-sink\src\main\avro'
- compile sparkflume.avdl to java files
  java -jar C:\Downloads\avro\avro-tools-1.8.1.jar idl sparkflume.avdl > sparkflume.avpr
  java -jar C:\Downloads\avro\avro-tools-1.8.1.jar compile -string protocol sparkflume.avpr ..\scala
- recompile your projects.